# CodeIgniter Query Result as Straight Array

Tags: codeigniter

I have function in CodeIgniter model and I want to simply put/copy 'active_date' record value into 'event_date' (in the same row that match with query). I tried give 'event_date' with straight value and it's work. I just have no idea to do that with the query result. Thanks!

```
public function postx_model()
  {   
    $data = array(
      'last_status' => $this->input->post('status'),
      );

    if( $this->input->post('status') == 'Active' )
    {
       $this->db->select('active_date');
       $this->db->where('customer_code', $this->input->post('customer_code') );
       $query = $this->db->get('customer_table');

    $data2 = array(
    'event_date' => $query,
    //'event_date' => '2013-09-14', //this is work
      );

      $dataComplete = $data + $data2;
      $this->db->where('customer_code', $this->input->post('customer_code') );
      $this->db->update('customer_table', $dataComplete); 
    }
    else
    {
    $this->db->where('customer_code', $this->input->post('customer_code') );
    $this->db->update('customer_table', $data); 
    }
  }
```

Comment: where is $this->db-select('active_date'); in next two queries.....

Comment: Hi Venkat, that was  only misstyped in my question. Do You have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$query = $this->db->select('active_date')
->from('customer_table')
->where('customer_code', $this->input->post('customer_code'))
->get()->row_array();
$data2 = array('event_date' => $query['active_date']);
```

Comment: thanks this is works. However I can remove 1st line $this->db->select and it still works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should like this:-

```
public function postx_model()
{   
    $data = array('last_status' => $this->input->post('status'));
    if( $this->input->post('status') == 'Active' )
    {
       $this->db->select('active_date');
       $this->db->where('customer_code', $this->input->post('customer_code') );
       $query = $this->db->get('customer_table');
       $result=$query->result_array();
       $data2 = array('event_date' => $result['active_date']);
       $dataComplete = $data + $data2;
       $this->db->where('customer_code', $this->input->post('customer_code') );          
       $this->db->update('customer_table', $dataComplete); 
    }
    else
    {
       $this->db->where('customer_code', $this->input->post('customer_code') );
       $this->db->update('customer_table', $data); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the result of your query and manipulate on result
   see the commented line below ...

```
public function postx_model()
  {   
   $data = array(
  'last_status' => $this->input->post('status'),
  );

if( $this->input->post('status') == 'Active' )
{
   $this->db->select('active_date');
   $this->db->where('customer_code', $this->input->post('customer_code') );
   $query = $this->db->get('customer_table');
   // getting result of query
   $result=$query->result();

//creating data array based on result data 
$data2 = array(
'event_date' => $result->active_date,
//'event_date' => '2013-09-14', //this is work
  );

  $dataComplete = $data + $data2;
  $this->db->where('customer_code', $this->input->post('customer_code') );
  $this->db->update('customer_table', $dataComplete); 
}
else
{
$this->db->where('customer_code', $this->input->post('customer_code') );
$this->db->update('customer_table', $data); 
}
```

}

Comment: Both your suggest and @Girish's unfortunately not work on me, even they are more look like in user_guide. Both resulting 1 Jan 1970 (though it not give the correct value). Thanks.

Comment: @mbeok you need to check what you get from the database and use strtotime to manipulate the date..

Answer (score 0):

observation: do you notice how this line keeps getting repeated over and over

```
  $this->input->post('customer_code') ;
```

suggestion: never use $this->input->post or anything like it inside database insert or update. just pass in variables or arrays that have been filtered, cleansed, validated and are ready to go.

```
  // adding TRUE enables xss clean 
  $customerCode = this->input->post('customer_code', TRUE) ;
```

now you can use $customerCode for any method - it will be clearer and easier to read - and if the form name changes - you only have to change it one place. and for a bonus we added xss cleaning. if you need to use it in more then one method:

```
 $this->customerCode = this->input->post('customer_code', TRUE) ;
```

now $this->customerCode will be available to any method in the class.

=====
edit 
*"What is the meaning it will be available to any method in the class?"* 
well -- that is the really cool thing about $this-> 
normally in a method (function) when you set a variable: $myvariable, you can only use it within the method. when you use $this->myvariable its instantly available to any method in the class.

which is cool but whats SUPER COOL, is that you can set $this->variable in your model constructer - such as the name of your database table, fields, etc. like $this->dbtable = 'acme_users'; $this->dbfields = 'id,first,last,email';

then you can use generic code like $this->dbtable, $this->dbfields in your methods. Another advantage is that you can **put very specific knowledge about your model up top in the constructor - and then be more abstract in the method code you write**. that makes it easier to reuse / extend.

Comment: nice, but not sure where should I declare the `$customerCode = $this->input->post('customer_code', TRUE) ;` I put it within my model function postx_model() and it just not work.

Comment: It should work in model or controller. do an echo and see if you are getting anything back: echo 'TEST HERE ' . $customerCode ;

Comment: yep, my fault, i did some change on routes.php and i forgot about that. Check with firebug and got the post request was internal server error. I have fixed that. Bytheway, what is different the `$customerCode =` method with the `$this->customerCode=` ? What is the meaning it will be available to any method in the class? Thanks